# Convert an XpathNodeIterator to a List<XElement>

Tags: c#, list, xelement, xpathnodeiterator

In C#, I sorted an RSS feed using **XpathExpression** and a self defined compare function for the field Publication Date.

I need to convert this sorted `XPathNodeIterator` object to a `List<XElement>` 'Generic Linq type' object. I've tried to use an intermediary data-type but did not have any luck.

Tried:

```
List<XElement> elements = new List<XElement>();
IEnumerable<XElement> sortedElements;
IEnumerable<XElement> newElements;

sortedElements = (IEnumerable <XElement>) iterator;
```

I've also tried using order by on the list but that was unsuccessful using only `List<XElement>`.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an `IEnumerable`, the easiest way to convert to an `IEnumerable<>` is to use `OfType`, like this:

```
var sortedElements = iterator.OfType<XPathNavigator>();
```

This will not give you `XElement` objects; that's part of a separate XML API. However, the `XPathNavigator` objects may have the data you need, so you can follow up with some sort of `Select` depending on what you need:

```
var elementValues = iterator.OfType<XPathNavigator>().Select(n => n.Value);
```

If you do want to use `System.Linq.Xml` stuff, you may be able to rewrite your XPath as LINQ on an `XDocument` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use XPathNavigator. I have to rewrite my sort function.

'var doc = XDocument.Load(url);' 'elements.AddRange(doc.XPathSelectElements(_xpath).ToList()); '

that is how the List <XElement> is being generated. Not my code and cannot be changed. I will have to run a sort compare method or new sort function. But I am unfamiliar with Linq.

Comment: if I use 
'sortElement = elements.OrderBy(element => element.Element("pubDate").Value);'

I get an error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?

Comment: You must be assigning the value to a `List<XElement>`. If you really _need_ it to be a list, you can add a `.ToList()` after your `.OrderBy()`.

Comment: Thank you. That seemed to get rid of the error. Yes unforntunately it has to be a list. OrderBy did not sort the list. This I am guessing is because the actual value of pubDate is a string Fri, DD Month YYYY HH:MM:SS -XXXX. And typecasting to an int would be invalid and incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but have you checked whether this works?

```
var xmlStrings = iterator.OfType<XPathNavigator>().Select(n => n.OuterXml).ToList();
var xmlElements = new List<XElement>();
xmlStrings.ForEach(el => xmlElements.Add(XElement.Parse(el)));
```